# Using a blazor server with signalR as a relay server

Tags: winforms, signalr, blazor

The goal is to use a Blazor server as a relay server using signalR.
I have little to no experience with blazor servers before this.
The Idea would be to connect a Winform/Xamarin client to this server, target the recipient using a name/id from an existing database, and relay the necessary info.

Hub:

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessageAsync(string user, string message)
    {
        //Context.UserIdentifier
        Debug.WriteLine(Context.UserIdentifier);
        Debug.WriteLine(Context?.User?.Claims.FirstOrDefault());
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message); ;
    }
    public Task DirectMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        return Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

As per documentation I'm trying to set the Context.UserIdentifier, I do however struggle with the authentication part. My program.cs looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var services = builder.Services;
services.AddTransient<IUserIdProvider, MyUserIdProvider>();
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{

options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        
        //var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
        var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/chathub"))
        {
            context.Token = accessToken;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
});

services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
services.AddSignalR();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

As for my Client (a winform test client) I tried something like this:

```
HubConnection chatHubConnection;

       chatHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("https://localhost:7109/chathub", options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token);
        })
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();



private async void HubConBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chatHubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
    {
        this.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var newMessage = $"{user}: {message}";
            MessagesLB.Items.Add(newMessage);
        });
    });

    try
    {
        await chatHubConnection.StartAsync();
        MessagesLB.Items.Add("Connected!");
        HubConBtn.Enabled = false;
        SendMessageBtn.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessagesLB.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As a first step I'm just trying to authenticate a user/check that it's in the live database, if so connect and fill out: Context.UserIdentifier so I can use this within the Hub. I understand that I probably need a middleware however I don't really know exactly how to test a connectionId/Jwt token or similar to get the user/connection.

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you don't know where and how to generate a JWT token.

For me the JWT token should be generated from the server, your hub.

POST api/auth and in the playload you give login + SHA256 password and returns JWT token.

Once you checked the user auth is correct in you DB you can issue the token.

To generate a JWT token I use this piece of code.

```
public string GenerateToken(IConfiguration Config, DateTime? expire)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, _id),
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role)
    };
    // ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Config["jwt:Secret"]);
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(bytes);
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    //Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        //Config.GetValue<string>("jwt:Issuer"),
        //Config.GetValue<string>("jwt:Issuer") + "/ressources",
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Config.GetValue<int>("jwt:ExpireMinute")),
        signingCredentials: creds);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

#edit

Look here to allow JWT for SignalR

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I also added this.

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
    auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I did find an example of a similar Generate token code. Where I lack in understanding is how to register the service that would return this token to the client. And if this would make the Context.UserIdentifier, or Context?.User?.Identity.Name be filled for the subsequent requests to the SignalR hub.

Comment: I confirm Context.User is correct with the two point I just add.

Comment: I found a solution to my specific problem and have added the explanation in the edit of this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72700003/blazor-server-authentication-jwt-for-signalr-everything-but-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use something like IdentityServer to handle the authentication. It's a free solution, also .NET based which takes very little configuration effort to offer you simple client credentials authentication and generate the token for you.

I did basically exactly what you're asking here: A WinForms application connecting to my signalR hub application on a remote server, using Bearer token - but I also have OIDC/OAUTH implemented with third party user account login.

IdentityServer offers a great repository of full examples that showing you all the flow - and with just a few lines of code changed, you have a fullblown authentication system, which can be enhanced easily.

With IdentityServer you get everything, even the corresponding extension methods that enable your signalR hub application to create the claims principal (aka user) from the claims included within your token.

Here you'll find all the examples and docs:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

If you hit any walls, just reply here and I'll try to help.